# Does anyone have a BSP example?

Tags: three.js, bsp-tree

Does anyone have an example of using BSP trees in ThreeJS that they could share or know about? I am looking at creating a terrain splatting example and would like to use a BSP (or perhaps octree...?) to help speed up the rendering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this octree source: https://github.com/collinhover/threeoctree

EDIT: There are now several three.js examples:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_octree.html

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_octree_raycasting.html

three.js r.60

Comment: Thanks WestLangley, I also found this if anyone is interested... https://gist.github.com/chandlerprall/1484619